# Change Default Locale Settings for Site Collection in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, regional-settings

Is it possible to change default locale for all sites in a site collection using Office 365?

I can't find any regional settings relating to site collections (and obviously don't have access to the web application).

Is it possible to change the default so newly created sites are correct?
Also, if not, can custom site templates store a custom locale?

Answer (score 1):

The property you are after is called LocaleId. It cannot be set after the site template has been set.

As for the new sites: how are you creating them? 
In the portal after you click 
SP Admin Centre>New>Private
you should have an option to choose the language.

From Powershell:
new-sposite -owner -url -storagequota -localeid

For English you should choose 1033. The full list you will find below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/goglobal/bb964664

Comment: When creating a site you can set the language, but if you select English it defaults to English(USA) locale. Which is a pain.

The powershell suggested cannot be used on SharePoint Online, which is the crux of the question.

Comment: Nick, the Powershell works for SPO. I have just tested to double-check with the following settings: New-SPOSite -Owner Me -Url https://*****.sha
repoint.com/sites/lgchange -StorageQuota 100 -localeid 1025 which created a lovely page in Arabic. If you are receiving an error, share the error.

Comment: Sorry you are correct about the powershell working. It still doesn't set the default locale for the site collection though - it just allows you to create a site and set the locale.

Comment: It sets the locale for the site collection. If you want to change the default language for your whole tenant, you have to contact Microsoft (there is no other way) and data loss may be involved.

Comment: I see you are still looking for a better answer :)  Maybe what you have in mind is SharePoint Online SDK and $ctx.Web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId=2057.

Answer (score 1):

8 years later and Microsoft still haven't addressed proper locale support in SharePoint. Even with a site's locale set, it has hardcoded MM/DD/YYYY all over the place: document library restore timeline, documents shared with us, the weather widget, .... plus of course all the admin portals.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the regional settings in the site collection setting. See the attachment
[image]

Comment: This is fine for individual sites but it doesn't solve it for an entire site collection, let alone all site collections.